# Declare large objects with many properties and functions in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I want to consume a global variable in my typescript code, which comes from different none typescript custom code.

I know that I can use the `declare` keyword and it works for simple variables.

But now I have a really huge object with many variables and functions in it. This would be a huge amount to declare everything in it, before I can use it.
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: `any` ?!?!?!?!?

Comment: Make a Typescript class which represents the object and export the class

Comment: @JonasW. Hahaha, simple as that. Thank you.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze That is exactly what I did not want to do. any type is just the right thing to do.

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb Yeah I understand. Kinda implied you know about the any solution! Sorry.